# How do I pipe an extracted filename in the terminal?

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, pipe

I have a `bz2` file which I can extract using the `bunzip2` command. This gives me a `tar` file which I would further like to extract. Now, how do I pipe the filename after the `bz2` extraction, to the `tar` extraction command?

I tried `bunzip2 <file.bz2> | tar -xvf`, but this doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this is to decompress the bz2-file to stdout and pipe this into tar:
`bunzip2 -c <file.bz2> | tar -xv`